# Can I whitelist a cloaked IP address for a 3rd party API?

Tags: linux, ip

A 3rd party API (Poloniex) requires an IP address to be whitelisted. In my case, my server's true IP needs to be whitelist which requires me to divulge it to users (which is a security hole). I'm looking for a solution to provide some sort of cloaked IP address that can be whitelisted.

I use CloudFlare for DNS which makes my public IP address different than the true one, but when whitelisting this IP, it doesn't work.

Are there any workarounds to provide some sort of alias IP that would act the same as the true IP for whitelisting? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fail to see why white-listing your ip-address with an API provider would lead to divulging it to your users?

But the typical solution which I would also recommend when for instance due to scaling  the real ip-addresses of your backend servers fluctuate is to route all the api requests that your servers/applications make through  a http proxy and then white-list the proxy servers ip-address(es).